# Unable to send attachment in emails using VBA macro code

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I intend to send a Company Profile as an email attachment along with the mail body to the intended customer list from the excel sheet carrying the client details ( Name,EmailID, etc. I am getting an error while i am compiling the code below " Compile Error: " Expected end of statement"

Email_ID from Excel

```
Sub Send_Email_from_Excel()
    Dim Email_ID As String
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim OutlookApp As Object
    Dim myAttachments As Object
    Dim Path As String
    Dim lastrow As Integer
    Dim Attachment As String
    Dim X As Integer
    X = 2
    Do While Sheet1.Cells(X, 1) <> " "
        For X = 2 To 4
            Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
            Set OutlookmailItem = OutlookApp.createitem(0)
            Set myAttachments = OutlookmailItem.Attachments
            Path = "C:\Users\Prashant\Desktop\HR SOL New.pdf"
            Email_ID = Sheet1.Cells(X, 1)
            Attachment = Path + FileName
            MsgBox Email_ID
            OutlookmailItem.To = Email_ID
            OutlookmailItem.CC = "enquiry@hr-solutions.net.in"
            OutlookmailitemBody = "Dear Sir," & vbCrLf& & "As per our telephonic conversation today," & vbCrLf& & " Awaiting your revrt asap"
            myAttachments.Add (Attachment)
            OutlookmailItem.display
            OutlookmailItem.send
            Email_ID = " "
            X = X + 1
        Loop
    Next X
    Set OutlookApp = Nothing
    Set OutlookmailItem = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Change the Positions of `Loop` and `Next`, they are in the wrong order.

Comment: If you format your code block as above, you can better see the to loops are crossed. The more I look at the loops though, the more I think one of them is redundant. I don't see why the For Next loop is needed at all.

Comment: Also `For X = 2 to 4` and `Next x` automatically increments on the loop - you don't need to `x=x+1`, unless you really want this to work for X=2 (first loop) then X = 4 (second time through) and not do for X=3 at all.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I use X for columns (being the X-axis) and Y for rows (being the Y-axis) but personal preferences aside, this should work:

```
Sub Send_Email_from_Excel()
    Dim Email_ID As String
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim OutlookApp As Object
    Dim myAttachments As Object
    Dim Path As String
    Dim lastrow As Integer
    Dim Attachment As String
    Dim X As Integer
    X = 2
    Do While Sheet1.Cells(X, 1) <> " " ' Keep going until the cell being read contains a single space?
        Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutlookmailItem = OutlookApp.createitem(0)
        Set myAttachments = OutlookmailItem.Attachments
        Path = "C:\Users\Prashant\Desktop\HR SOL New.pdf"
        Email_ID = Sheet1.Cells(X, 1)
        Attachment = Path + FileName
        MsgBox Email_ID
        OutlookmailItem.To = Email_ID
        OutlookmailItem.CC = "enquiry@hr-solutions.net.in"
        Outlookmailitem.Body = "Dear Sir," & vbCrLf& & "As per our telephonic conversation today," & vbCrLf& & " Awaiting your revrt asap"
        myAttachments.Add (Attachment)
        ' OutlookmailItem.display ' I'm not sure you need this if you're using .Send
        OutlookmailItem.send
        X = X + 1 ' -alternatively, if you want it to only look at ever other line as your redundant loop suggests, use X = X + 2
    Loop

    Set OutlookApp = Nothing
    Set OutlookmailItem = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Entered the code given above but it is not picking the email ID from Excel Sheet & the subject Line & Body Message is also  not been taken from the code it is completely blank

Comment: I've edited the code as I notice you had a typo (which I'd copied) in the `.Body` line.

Comment: As for the *Subject* - you don't have a `OutlookmailItem.Subject` line - so you're not getting that.

Comment: And the Email_ID? That is picking up whatever is in A2, A3, A4.. etc. **Do you have data in those cells on Sheet1** ?